# one database with multiple tables

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a database file that has multiple tables.
How do I search on all the tables.
I've tested it only works for a table.
Code:

```
 cu = myDB.rawQuery("select * from TABLE_A or Table_B ...  where " + field + " Like '%" + word + "%' group by " + field, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

[image: JOINs Examples]

this is that you need. For more information, you can read more on this website [w3schools sql tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/)